# Can filter and order point to different column name in google cloud datastore?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to store my data in datastore and I am retrieving it back as well once it is stored. I can able to filter my data and order the order only with the column I used in filter. But if I try to use some other column for ordering I am getting error.

What I tried:

```
def list_tasks(client):
    query = client.query(kind='Task1')
    query.add_filter('columnA','=', 'A')
    query.order = ['Created']    # in datetime
    return list(query.fetch())
```

The above is throwing me error

```
FailedPrecondition: 400 no matching index found
```

But when I change the order to columnA, it works. Is there any way that I can give different columns in both add_filter and order.

Please advice

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you add this index into your index.yaml?

Comment: Can you include your `index.yaml` in the question?

Comment: I was unable to find any limitation to use different columns to filter and sort in the API documentation: [https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/queries.html#google.cloud.datastore.query.Query]

The problem should be something else. Could you share your index.yaml?